# Почему перестал работать bash-скрипт отправки в Яндекс.Диск?

Tags: bash, резервное-копирование, webdav, яндекс-диск

До недавних пор у меня замечательно работал скрипт для отправки файла не Яндекс.Диск:

```
 #!/bin/bash
   # username:password - имя пользователя и пароль к аккаунту Яндекса  
   curl -T file.pdf --user username:password https://webdav.yandex.ru/
```

Сейчас выдаёт ошибку:

```
You are not authorized to see this!
```

... Логично, что работоспособность связки логин-пароль проверена не один раз.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

У меня без проблем все работает так:

`curl -T клан.png -u логин:пароль https://webdav.yandex.ru/`

curl 7.35.0

Comment: Спасибо, извините за беспокойство, скрипт всё-таки рабочий, проблема была в излишней криптоустойчивости пароля (часть пароля не распозновались)

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно в Вашем пароле есть спец. символы и командная оболочка bash считает их конструкцией языка.
Например знак $.